# Testing normality with Confidence Intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, normalization, qq-plot

I've read an [article](https://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/normality/dealing-non-normal-data-strategies-and-tools/) that talks about transforming non-normal data to normal data. In the article it says:

"In this case, normality clearly cannot be assumed; the p-value is less than 0.05 and more than 5 percent of the data points are outside the 95 percent confidence interval."

[image]

I don't understand the process behind generating the three purple lines. I do understand that the red line represents the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for the sample data, but I don't understand how the three purple lines are generated - it seems to be the upper, mean, and lower confidence interval. What formula do you use? Hopefully if you can provide python code snippet, it would be great

How are these purple lines generated?

Comment: One can only guess--but regardless, they're superfluous.  (An educated guess is that they are an ordinary least squares fit and confidence bands for it, but since an OLS fit is not suited for points on a probability plot, the confidence bands are nonsense.)  It's obvious these points don't lie along any reference line.  A standard method of constructing a reference line for a QQ plot picks two quantiles of the data, such as the 16th and 84th, which thereby correspond to two points on the probability plot, and just draws the line connecting them.

Comment: Note that the red curve is not itself the cdf of a sample (i.e. not the [ecdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function)). Since times are necessarily positive you wouldn't expect them to be normal; there are several common models for times like this, of which exponential would be the simplest (and might be roughly plausible in this case).